# QDialog::accept does not respond to close

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

my code is

```
void BTSettingsTab::accept()
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    char send[64] = {0}, temp[32];
    int s, client, bytes_read, bytes_written;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = (bdaddr_t){{0,0,0,0,0,0}};//*BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    listen(s, 1);
    // accept one connection
    client = ::accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    strcat(send,passwd);
    strcat(send,",");
    snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%ld", mobile_num);
    strcat(send,temp);
    strcat(send,",");
    snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%ld", imei);
    strcat(send,temp);
    //Thread_data * _data = new Thread_data(&s, send);
    //pthread_create(&threadId,0,writeThread,_data);


}
```

when I try to close the dialog box using x symbol, it does not close. What to do? I have opened a server socket and listening for connection. That may be the reason. How to solve?

modified code with select

```
void BTSettingsTab::accept()
{
    int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 64;
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    char send[64] = {0}, temp[32];
    int s, client, bytes_read, bytes_written, maxfd;
  int srvsock, peersock, j, result, result1, sent, len;
  fd_set readset, tempset;
  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE+1];
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = (bdaddr_t){{0,0,0,0,0,0}};//*BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    listen(s, 1);
    // accept one connection
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
       FD_SET(s, &readset);
       maxfd = s;
       do {
          memcpy(&tempset, &readset, sizeof(tempset));

          result = select(maxfd + 1, &tempset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

          if (result == 0) {
             printf("select() timed out!\n");
          }
          else if (result < 0 && errno != EINTR) {
             printf("Error in select(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
          }
          else if (result > 0) {

             if (FD_ISSET(s, &tempset)) {
                len = sizeof(rem_addr);
                socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

                peersock = ::accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
                if (peersock < 0) {
                   printf("Error in accept(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
                }
                else {
                   FD_SET(peersock, &readset);
                   maxfd = (maxfd < peersock)?peersock:maxfd;
                }
                FD_CLR(s, &tempset);
             }

             for (j=0; j<maxfd+1; j++) {
                if (FD_ISSET(j, &tempset)) {

                   do {
                      result = recv(j, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
                   } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);

                   if (result > 0) {
                      buffer[result] = 0;
                      printf("Echoing: %s\n", buffer);
                      sent = 0;

                      do {
                         result1 = ::send(j, buffer+sent, result-sent, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
                         if (result1 > 0)
                            sent += result1;
                         else if (result1 < 0 && errno != EINTR);
                            break;
                       } while (result > sent);

                   }
                   else if (result == 0) {
                      ::close(j);
                      FD_CLR(j, &readset);
                   }
                   else {
                      printf("Error in recv(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
                   }
                }      // end if (FD_ISSET(j, &tempset))
             }      // end for (j=0;...)
          }      // end else if (result > 0)
       } while (1);
    //client = ::accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
    /*ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    strcat(send,passwd);
    strcat(send,",");
    snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%ld", mobile_num);
    strcat(send,temp);
    strcat(send,",");
    snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%ld", imei);
    strcat(send,temp);*/
    //Thread_data * _data = new Thread_data(&s, send);
    //pthread_create(&threadId,0,writeThread,_data);

    QDialog::accept();
}
```

select is used to poll the socket descriptor s. As new connection comes, it is stored in peersock. Then select the socket descriptor peersock for data. If data comes read.If more accept descriptor comes, it is handled by while(1)

Comment: If `BTSettingsTab` is derived from `QDialog`, you should rename `void BTSettingsTab::accept()` to something that will not override `QDialog::accept`.

Comment: yes BTSettingsTab is derived from QDialog. But I did not get your point how to renameBTSettingsTab::accept(using typedef or what)

Comment: If I change the name accept to accept1, then it will not invoke the OK button of QDialogButtonBox. I am not getting your point what do u mean to say

Answer (score 4):

The `QDialog::accept` slot sets the accepted state and closes the dialog box.

You have a class `BTSettingsTab` derived from `QDialog` which overrides the `virtual void accept()` member function.

If your implementation of `void accept()` should perform the same function as `QDialog::accept`, you will need to call it explicitly at the end of your function.

For example:

```
void BTSettingsTab::accept()
{
    ...
    QDialog::accept();
}
```

Comment: I added QDialog::accept at the end , but the problem is still there

Comment: Just looking at your code again, does `::accept` block?

Comment: yes, I am thinking to add select, but still there is problem, because select is in while loop,I am pasting my code